Метод нахождения сущности по совокупности связанных с ней в отношении "Многие-ко-многим" сущностей Spring Data JPA
Есть две сущности, связанные отношением "Многие-ко-многим". Для примера скажем, что это авторы и книги:



Автор
Книга




38
52


41
52


66
52


38
101


41
101


66
101


38
522


66
387



Предоставляет ли Spring Data JPA такой шаблонный запрос (типа findBy...), который позволит найти все книги, связанные с заданным списком авторов в совокупности?
То есть, в приведённом выше примере я хочу найти все книги, связанные с набором авторов [38, 41, 66], при этом меня не интересуют книги, написанные авторами по отдельности или в каком-нибудь другом их сочетании, кроме заданной тройки.
Условно говоря, продолжая пример, запрос вида
Set<Book> findAllByAllAuthorsId(Set<Integer> authorsId)

при подаче на вход списка авторов
Authors [38, 41, 66]

должен вернуть список из двух книг:
Books [52, 101]

Я знаю о том, что Spring Data JPA умеет распознавать подстроку In в названии метода, но для моей задачи это не подходит. Если в метод
Set<Book> findAllByAuthorsIdIn(Set<Integer> authorsId)

подать тот же список авторов, то будут найдены в том числе и книги с идентификаторами 522 и 387.
Как можно решить эту задачу средствами Spring Data JPA?

Вряд ли получится создать методы в JPA репозитории, используя ключевые слова.  Скорее всего придётся придумать нативные запросы с использованием функций БД, чтобы получить массив/коллекцию идентификаторов (типа array_agg в PostgreSQL) и затем отфильтровать по такой коллекции

Хм, ну да, получается, что это даже в самой БД непросто сделать, не говоря о том, чтобы такие действия проворачивал фреймворк. Спасибо за комментарий. Я пока что по-другому решил. Если в продолжение примера говорить, то достаю множество книг и нахожу среди них те, у которых множество авторов соответствует заданному. Фактически там у сущности ("книги") есть ещё несколько связей (одиночных айдишников, FK), которые я указываю в JPA-методе, поэтому в итоге остаётся пройтись по заведомо небольшому множеству.
